# WebBrowserTask fails to open .doc

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open a document hosted in dropbox public folder. I'm able to open same document from IE. But when i try to do same, my program does nothing. 
Same program works fine with pdf hosted at same place. In case of pdf, browsertask launches pdf reader(app i installed). 
Here is the code i use:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1967630/new.doc", UriKind.Absolute);            
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

And in case of any problem, how do i handle "failed to navigate" kind of case?

Comment: "Test document." how do I claim my prize?

Comment: send me your bank account number and password :)
I will transfer prize money to you.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me for both Emulator and Device on mango.

However, if you are on NoDo, you must do the code like this:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.URL = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1967630/new.doc";            
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Comment: URL is obsolete. And somehow even using this didn't help, on emulator and device.